# Remote Wildfly Logs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logging, wildfly

I am using JBoss Tools for eclipse to deploy to a remote Wildfly (10) server.  I am using the 'server is externally managed' option, and I can deploy my application just fine, the problem is Wildfly's console output is not displayed in the Eclipse console.  It seems like Eclipse will only capture the Wildfly console output if Eclipse is configured to start Wildfly via the management interface.

Is there any way to tell Eclipse to connect to the console of an already running Wildfly?

If that is not possible, are there any other options to view remote Wildfly logs in the Eclipse console?